# get original content of a pdf signed with itextsharp

Tags: .net, pdf, itext, digital-signature

I'm trying to get the original document of a signed PDF in order to compare it's hash with an stored doc.

This is really easy when the document has several signatures, with acrobat reader you can go the previous revision of the document save it and that's it.

Surprisingly this does not work with the first signature, where there is no straight forward way to get the original data.

As it is not possible to do it with the reader I have tried programatically with iTextSharp. However although I have googled deeply I have not found how to do it. The only relevant post I found is this [one](http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/Signature-PDF-How-obtain-Original-PDF-td2167992.html) but no solution is offered.

Has anyone faced this problem and found a solution?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I put here the code that extracts the data based on the response of mkl. Read the comments of the response to beware of the problem with the unfixed length of the non signed PDFs.

```
String sOriginalText = File.ReadAllText("FileSigned.pdf", Encoding.Default);
int sTrailerNumberPosition = sOriginalText.LastIndexOf("]/Prev ") + "]/Prev ".Length;
int sTrailerNumberEndPosition = sOriginalText.IndexOf(">", sTrailerNumberPosition);
String sTrailerIndex = sOriginalText.Substring(sTrailerNumberPosition, sTrailerNumberEndPosition -sTrailerNumberPosition);
int iTrailerIndexPosition = sOriginalText.IndexOf(sTrailerIndex + "\r\n%%EOF");
int iEndPosition = sOriginalText.IndexOf("%%EOF", iTrailerIndexPosition) + "%%EOF".Length;
String sOutText = sOriginalText.Substring(0, iEndPosition);
File.WriteAllText("c:/OriginalFile.pdf", sOutText, Encoding.Default);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether or not your task *to get the original document of a signed PDF* is realizable at all, depends on how the signature originally was applied.

1. If the signature was applied in **append** mode (i.e. according to the language of the PDF specification [ISO 32000-1:2008](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) as an **incremental update**, cf. section 7.5.6), you merely have to cut off this appended, incremental update revision.

   As you have a stored document which presumably after signing has become the document you inspect, you can simply cut the signed file at the length of the stored one and the compare, e.g. using hashes. This suffices to show that the signed document is derived from your original one. There may have been other, intermediary revisions, though, as you might just have cut off multiple incremental updates.

   In general you can find the prior revision by following the **/Prev** trailer entry of your signed PDF to the cross reference table of the prior revision and from there move onwards to the document end marker **%%EOF** because in an incremental update

   > the added trailer shall contain all the entries except the Prev entry (if present) from the previous trailer, whether modified or not. In addition, the added trailer dictionary shall contain a Prev entry giving the location of the previous cross-reference section (see Table 15). Each trailer shall be terminated by its own end-of-file (%%EOF) marker.

   In case of PDFs using cross reference streams instead of cross reference tables, there is the analogous entry in the cross-reference stream dictionary:

   > (Present only if the file has more than one cross-reference stream; not meaningful in hybrid-reference files; see 7.5.8.4, "Compatibility with Applications That Do Not Support Compressed Reference Streams") The byte offset in the decoded stream from the beginning of the file to the beginning of the previous cross-reference stream. This entry has the same function as the Prev entry in the trailer dictionary (Table 15).

   You should be aware, though, that the appended, incremental update revision can contain other changes in addition to the signature. Thus, even if the previous revision corresponds with your stored document, you still only know that the signed document is based on your saved one.
2. If the signature was **not** applied in **append** mode, you are out of luck: Programs manipulating PDFs (e.g. for signing) might completely rearrange the binary contents of your document, possibly even renumbering objects, changing compression, removing unused objects, etc., while the appearance of the document remains the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot mkl for this relevant answer. The signature I have is in append mode so looks like I am lucky. :) I have compared both PDF with beyond compare and as you explain the signature is at the last part of the file. Do you know if there is any way to extract that last part of the file programatically with iText? Or should I have to code it to check where the las Prev points to and cut it from scratch?

Comment: iText only allows the extraction of signed revisions. One reason for this restriction is that the end of an unsigned revision is not exactly determined. When you find the **%%EOF** marker of it followed by a carriage return and a line feed, you cannot be sure whether the carriage return and possibly even the line feed belong to the old revision or not. In your case you can apply heuristics as you have a stored document which is a candidate for the precursor revision.

Comment: Thanks again for the explanation. Actually I don't have the orignal document but it's hash. So the only "problem" is knowing if the CR+LF belongs to the original or not? In that case I could calculate the hash with and without the CR, and the CR+LF and check if any of them matches with the stored one. Would this approach be correct?

Comment: It would be better if you at least could extend your data storage to also contain the former file size. The problem is that while the last line of a PDF according to the standard has to contain the **%%EOF** marker and only it, there are many PDFs in the wild that have some additional trash bytes following. Therefore it depends on how strictly the original documents follow the standard.

Comment: wow, so complicated. Many thanks for all these details. I would vote your answer but I don't have yet enough reputation :)

Comment: Just one more question for curiosity. If there is no direct way to get the original data of a signed content, how does Acrobat Reader verify the signature. I mean, it should get the original data recalculate the hash and compare it to the hash within the signature, so in someway it need to get the original data.

Comment: No, the hash is not calculated for the former revision. Instead the new revision is built with a gap for the signature container, then the hash is calculated for the new revision with the exception of the gap, this hash is signed, and the resulting signature container is put into that gap.